# Vestax mixer to Audacity - only hearing one turntable

Tags: audacity, analog, record

I have a Vestax PMC25 mixer going to an isolator with 2 Technic 1200s. I'm trying to record onto a Mac using Audacity recording software. I can only get 1 turntable to record. The only output working is a phono out.

Comment: There is no _phono output_. Only on the turntables. Do you know what you are doing with the mixer? How have you connected it to the mac? Have you used phono or line inputs? What outputs have you used? Is the crossfader not in the centre?...

Comment: I do know what I'm doing with the mixer when mixing. I am confused with the addition of the isolator, powered monitor speaker and the turntables to the computer. Im using an  interface that is line or phono to USB. I don't have a crossfader because I've changed it to rotary knobs. it is set to middle. I have to move speakers an try the line out as suggested before. Thank you

Comment: Ok. I asked you if you know what your doing because with some mixers, (like mine) you can switch the turntables to different channels, and flip the Xfader, etc. The isolator connections should be straight forward. If you are still having trouble, [edit your question](http://sound.stackexchange.com/posts/39765/edit) and add more details about your setup. It'll be a lot easer to help you then.

Answer (score -1):

The mixer has two individual phono outputs assigned to each of the line inputs. That's the reason Audacity records only one turntable channel.

Connecting the Line Out output to the computer will make Audacity able to record the mixed signal.

[image]

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood you, this answer is **wrong**. You have highlighted in red the phono **inputs**. **There are no _phono outputs._**

Comment: Yeah, the blue selection is correct, and the XLR out(L/R) are just a balanced version of that Line out(L/R).These are sometimes called the `main outs`. The booth out is a Line out(L/R) for the booth(seperately controllable). But the rest are inputs. `PGM 1` and `PGM 2` are switchable inputs for turntables/devices.